# QObject::connect: No such signal - QT and OpenCV SIGNAL and connect() error

Tags: c++, opencv, user-interface, computer-vision, qt5

I'm working on a computer vision project, an interactable surface that must handle user interactions through the video feed recognising the user's hands. The system recognizes the user's finger and map it on a GUI. I've developed the solution in Visual Studio 2017 using OpenCV for the video processing stuff, QT 5 to build the GUI and arduino to check the click on the surface. At the moment I've to controll a QTPushButton using the arduino serial output, that controll a boolean (isChecked) in the main class of the C++ program, I've read a lot about SIGNAL and SLOT in QT but when I trigger a SIGNAL using arduino serial connection and I handle the signal with connect() method in the MainWindow interface the system responds with the error : **QObject::connect: No such signal QPushButton::valueChangedButton1(unsigned int)**.

The program failed to **connect(button1, SIGNAL(valueChangedButton1(unsigned int)), this, SLOT(button1clicked()));**, in the 
**MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)** instance.

SerialPort.h is an utility class to handle serial output from arduino. I've tried to put the connect() method in the while cycle of openCV but doesn't work.

**MainWindow.h**

```
#define NSAMPLES 7
#define ORIGCOL2COL COLOR_BGR2HLS
#define COL2ORIGCOL COLOR_HLS2BGR
#define PI 3.14159

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore/qcoreapplication.h>
#include <QtGui/qtguiglobal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "SerialPort.h"

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {

      Q_OBJECT

      public: 

           MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR); 

      private: 

           void initializationClicked(); 
           void stopCapture(); 
           void button1clicked(); 
           void button2clicked(); 

      signals: 

           void valueChangedButton1(unsigned int value);

      private:

        QPushButton *startCapture; 
        QPushButton *releaseCapture; 

        QPushButton *button1; 
        QPushButton *button2; 

        QLabel *interactionLabel;
        QLabel *interactionType; 
        QFont f, i; 
        char *PORT;
        bool b1Over, b2Over, isChecked; 

        // opencv stuff
        cv::VideoCapture cap; 
        cv::Mat src; 

        // arduino stuff
        char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
        char incomingData[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
        int intFromArduino;
        char *port;
        int fromArduino;
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

using namespace cv; 

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)

{   

    f =  QFont("Arial", 12, QFont::Bold);
    i = QFont("Arial", 10, QFont::Black);

    PORT = "\\\\.\\COM5"; 

    width = 600; 
    height = 380; 

    setMinimumSize(width, height); 

    startCapture = new QPushButton("INIT SYSTEM", this);
    startCapture->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, height - 120), QSize(100, 50)));
    connect(startCapture, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(initializationClicked()));

    releaseCapture = new QPushButton("KILL SYSTEM", this);
    releaseCapture->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, height - 60), QSize(100, 50)));
    connect(releaseCapture, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(stopCapture()));

    button1 = new QPushButton("BUTTON 1", this);
    button1->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(width / 2 - 100, height - 120), QSize(150, 100)));
    b1 = Point(width / 2 - 100, height - 120);  

    // receive the signal
    connect(button1, SIGNAL(valueChangedButton1(unsigned int)), this, SLOT(button1clicked()));

    button2 = new QPushButton("BUTTON 2", this);
    button2->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(width / 2 + 100, height - 120), QSize(150, 100)));
    b2 = Point(width / 2 + 100, height - 120); 


    interactionLabel = new QLabel(this); 
    interactionLabel->setText("log: ");
    interactionLabel->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 15), QSize(200, 20))); 
    interactionLabel->setFont(f); 

    interactionType = new QLabel(this); 
    interactionType->setText("kind of interaction"); 
    interactionType->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(110,15), QSize(250, 20)));
    interactionType->setFont(i);

}

void MainWindow::initializationClicked()
{
    controllMainVideoFlow(); 
}
void MainWindow::controllMainVideoFlow()
{
    SerialPort arduino(PORT); 
    cap = VideoCapture(0);
    if(!cap.isOpen())
    {
       cout << "no video feed" << endl; 
    }else
    {
       if(arduino.isConnected())
        {
           while(cap.isOpen())
          {
            cap >> src; 
            arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH); 
            fromArduino = strlen(output); 
            if(fromArduino == 0)
            {
              isChecked = false; 
             }
            else if(fromArduino != 0)
             {
               isChecked = true;

               // emit the signal 
               emitSignalB1(); 
             }
          imshow("SOURCE", src); 

          qApp->processEvents();

          if (cv::waitKey(30) == 'q') break;
          }
       cap.release(); 
       src.release(); 
      }
    }
 }

void MainWindow::emitSignalB1()
{
    // emit the signal 
    emit valueChangedButton1(fromArduino);
}
void MainWindow::stopCapture()
{
    interactionType->setText("system killed");
    cap.release();
    src.release();
    destroyAllWindows(); 
}
void MainWindow::button1clicked()
{
    interactionType->setText("button 1 clicked");
}

void MainWindow::button2clicked()
{
    interactionType->setText("button 2 clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
connect(button1, SIGNAL(valueChangedButton1(unsigned int)), this, SLOT(button1clicked()));
```

Actually, there is no such signal called `valueChangedButton1()` in `QPushButton`. You get this error because `button1` is a `QPushButton`.

You defined this signal in the `MainWindow` class, so you have to connect the signal from a `MainWindow` instance, not from a `QPushButton` instance.

You could write instead:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(valueChangedButton1(unsigned int)), this, SLOT(button1clicked()));
//      ^
//      Not button1
```

This will fix your error.
But as it's not clear for me what you really want to do, I'm not sure if it is what you really want.

---

By the way, I think this is a typo but, in your header, you declared your signal as `signal:` instead of `signals:` (a 's' is missing).

---

**EDIT:** I would advise you to not use the old macros `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` anymore. You should use the [new syntax instead](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Moreover, as the new syntax makes explicit from where the signals and slots are called, the origin of this error would have been obvious.